# How to deal with large feedback cycles in Agile

Tags: agile, project-management, scrum, management

Our project methodology is recently migrated from Waterfall Model to Agile, and the development and QA team is given proper training on that. Now, one of the Agile Strategies is *"Small Feedback cycles"*. But our product owner is still giving feedback after 2-3 sprints. That in turn results to major functional changes in the application and sometimes we have to work on a particular module from scratch.

Is there a way to deal with this? How to do proper impact analysis before suggesting major functional changes? Or with large feedback cycles, is it better to use Waterfall Model only?

Is it required to train the customer about Agile methodology as much as it required to train the development and QA team about Agile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we quit trying to do agile if QA takes 12 weeks?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96520/should-we-quit-trying-to-do-agile-if-qa-takes-12-weeks)

Comment: @gnat Problem is our QA team is trained and they perform their duties very well, but the feedback from the product owner is late than anticipated. So is it required to train the client as well with the team?

Comment: It is though to do agile if your customer is not agile. It is not uncommon that getting external buy-in is the hardest part when moving existing projects to agile.

Comment: I see, your question is closer to this one then: [Can Agile be accomplished without client involvement?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135234/can-agile-be-accomplished-without-client-involvement)

Comment: Your question seems to be about project management. Maybe you should try http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "later"? Do you have a review meeting after each sprint and does the PO approve the stories that are done?

Comment: @nvoigt: There is a tag for project-management here too. Am I getting confused in this regard?

Comment: @nvoigt : After 2-3 sprints the product owner is reminded of new requirements or some major functional changes, that we need to incorporate

Comment: Well, my take on it is that it's a good question for this site if your PM problems influence the software development. I think your question might be a better fit over there, because you'd have the same problem if you weren't developing software but laying bricks using Scrum and your current setup.

Comment: If you are having to rework particular modules from scratch, more than almost never, then either your development team does not know how to do a reasonable job designing the software, your team is horrible at eliciting the requirements or your customer has just invented some new requirements. Neither Agile, Waterfall or any other methodology can fix any of these issues. The worst case scenario that should occur if a module needs to be redesigned is change some interfaces, copy, paste and tweak the existing implementation to match the new interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it required to train the customer about Agile methodology as much as it required to train the development and QA team about Agile?

Simple answer: Yes. Agile only works well if everybody involved takes part. And since agile is mostly about *communication* and *involving the customer*, it won't work if they do not take part. **The product owner is part of the team.**

It is possible to assign a **proxy product owner** that takes the role of the customer, if the decision makers are too busy or care too less to get involved. But she has to take responsibility and should understand the customer and their needs well enough to make decisions for them.

So you should first try everything to make the customer understand the process and the importance of feedback. Then actively get them involved. For starters, invite them to the sprint reviews instead of using asynchronous communication like email.

Comment: So basically, we have to get some onsite coordinator as a proxy product owner?

Comment: If everything fails, yes. But be transparent about it. And first ask yourself if *you* really tried everything to get the customer involved and make him part of the team. This is your job.

Answer (score 2):

Does the customer feel like this is working? As a customer I would want to work out a better system so I'm not paying to have you make corrections and redo things that could have been pointed out sooner.

You could try to make your sprints a little longer as long as it doesn't get too long. Also, there is no law that says one sprint must immediately follow the next one. If you finish a sprint and the client can't meet for 2 weeks, put development on hold.

They either make themselves available or live with the delays. Otherwise, they pay extra for things that could have been caught in shorter feedback loops. As long as they're understand and are willing to pay the extra money, at some point it's not your problem.